# Service worker won't install when I try to cache xxx.worker.js

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-worker, cachestorage, worker-loader

I have the following service worker code in my Vue app:

**main.js**

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').catch(function() {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed.');
  });
}
```

**service-worker.js**

```
let currCacheName = 'premium-poker-tools-5';

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(currCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      let promise = cache.addAll([
        '/',
        'app.js',
        'c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js',
        'f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js',
        'static/logo.png',
        'static/favicon.png',
        'static/loading.svg',
        'static/cards/ace-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/king-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/queen-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/jack-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/ten-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/nine-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/eight-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/seven-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/six-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/five-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/four-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/three-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/two-of-clubs.png',
        'static/cards/ace-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/king-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/queen-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/jack-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/ten-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/nine-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/eight-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/seven-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/six-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/five-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/four-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/three-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/two-of-spades.png',
        'static/cards/ace-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/king-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/queen-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/jack-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/ten-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/nine-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/eight-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/seven-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/six-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/five-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/four-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/three-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/two-of-hearts.png',
        'static/cards/ace-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/king-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/queen-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/jack-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/ten-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/nine-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/eight-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/seven-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/six-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/five-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/four-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/three-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/cards/two-of-diamonds.png',
        'static/feedback/1.png',
        'static/feedback/2.png',
        'static/feedback/3.png',
        'static/feedback/4.png',
        'static/feedback/flop-selector.png',
        'static/feedback/green-grid-squares.png',
        'static/feedback/user-set-range-to-simulate-to-street.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/1.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/2.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/3.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/4.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/5.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/6.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/7.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/8.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/9.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/10.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/11.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/12.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/13.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/14.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/15.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/16.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/17.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/18.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/19.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/20.png',
        'static/guides/beginners-guide/21.png',
        'static/guides/faq/double-counting/1.png',
        'static/guides/faq/hit-percentage-calculation/1.png',
        'static/guides/faq/hit-percentage-calculation/2.png',
        'static/guides/faq/hit-percentage-calculation/3.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/1.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/2.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/3.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/4.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/5.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/6.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/7.png',
        'static/guides/faq/insights/8.png',
        'static/guides/faq/set-checks-to-default/1.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/1.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/2.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/3.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/4.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/5.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/6.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/7.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/8.png',
        'static/guides/quick-guide/save-load-scenario.png',
        'static/home/1.png',
        'static/home/2.png',
        'static/home/3.png',
        'static/settings/equity-calculator-insights-not-visible.png',
        'static/settings/equity-calculator-insights-visible.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-checkboxes-collapsed-1.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-checkboxes-collapsed-2.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-checkboxes-included-1.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-checkboxes-included-2.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-hands.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-insights-not-visible.png',
        'static/settings/outcome-analyzer-insights-visible.png',
        'static/settings/saved-ranges-1.png',
        'static/settings/saved-ranges-2.png',
        'static/settings/saved-ranges-3.png',
        'static/settings/saved-ranges-4.png',
        'static/settings/included-selectors/double-slider-selector.png',
        'static/settings/included-selectors/log-double-slider-selector.png',
        'static/settings/included-selectors/saved-ranges-selector.png',
        'static/settings/included-selectors/single-slider-selector.png',
        'static/settings/included-selectors/tier-and-category-selector.png',
        'static/settings/tiers/tiers.png',
        'static/settings/visual/dont-show-num-combos-in-range.png',
        'static/settings/visual/green-grid-squares.png',
        'static/settings/visual/multicolored-grid-squares.png',
        'static/settings/visual/show-num-combos-in-range.png',
      ]).then(function () {
        console.log('Successfully cached everything.')
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Problem caching: ', error);
      });

      return promise;
    }).catch(function () {
      console.error('Error with caches.open or cache.addAll');
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function getOldCachesThatBeginWithPremiumPokerToolsDash (cacheNames) {
        return cacheNames.filter(function (cacheName) {
          return cacheName.startsWith('premium-poker-tools-') && (cacheName !== currCacheName);
        });
      })
      .then(function removeOldCachesThatBeginWithPremiumPokerToolsDash (oldCachesThatBeginWithPremiumPokerToolsDash) {
        let removeCachePromises = [];

        oldCachesThatBeginWithPremiumPokerToolsDash.forEach(function (oldCacheThatBeginsWithPremiumPokerToolsDash) {
          removeCachePromises.push(caches.delete(oldCacheThatBeginsWithPremiumPokerToolsDash));
        });

        return Promise.all(removeCachePromises);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }

      return fetch(event.request);
    }).catch(function () {
      console.error('Error trying to match event request to cache.');
    })
  );
});
```

When I comment out `'c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js'` and `'f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js'`, it works fine. But when I uncomment them, here's what happens:

- I start off going to the Dev Tools and unregistering any service workers and deleting anything in Cache Storage so that I start off with a clean slate.
- I load `localhost:8080`.
- The service worker stays in the `installing` state.
- In Cache Storage, I see that `c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js` and `f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js` have been successfully cached.
- However, "Successfully cached everything." isn't being logged to the console. But "Problem caching: " isn't being logged either.

I understand that [the promise you pass to event.waitUntil() lets the browser know when your install completes, and if it was successful.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#install) So clearly there is some issue going on with the promise. But I don't know what the issue is. It's not hitting the `.then` block or the `.catch` block, and when I look at Cache Storage in the Dev Tools, it appears that `'c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js'` and `'f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js'` *are* being successfully cached.

Edit: I am using [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader). I get the feeling that the issue is related to how the worker files are loaded, but I don't see why there would be a problem, because when I go to `localhost:8080/c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js` or `localhost:8080/f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js`, I get back the JS file.

Also, I have made sure that prefixes in `c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js` and `f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js` are accurate. Eg. that `c7d016677eb7e912bc40` and `f328c7e2b379df12fa4c` are accurate.

Update:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the service worker's statue reported by chrome? is it `waiting to activated` with an orange icon beside it

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher The status is `installing`, which comes before the `waiting to be activated` state. I added pictures to demonstrate.

Comment: Check the URL <site>/ngsw/state that may some errors in there.

Comment: @PeterS I don't see any requests being made to `/ngsw/state` in the network tab. When I visit `/ngsw/state` - eg type it in to the URL bar and press enter - the response to `GET /ngsw/state` is just my `index.html` file.

Comment: @PeterS It [seems](https://gist.github.com/alxhub/76aa639d9a37cdca30938f7938d9146c#ngswstate) that `/ngsw/state` is specific to service workers in the context of Angular. I am using Vue.

Comment: @AdamZerner yes sorry it is, you may want to add that to your list of tags.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work how you think it does:

```
caches.open(currCacheName).then(function(cache) {
  let promise = cache.addAll([
```

You are defining a variable called `promise` here, but it doesn't replace `cache`, which is the promise which needs to be fulfilled.

You have a load of assets to cache and then:

```
 'static/settings/visual/show-num-combos-in-range.png',
      ]).then(function () {
        console.log('Successfully cached everything.')
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Problem caching: ', error);
      });
```

You don't return anything here, so `.then` won't run, but it's not an error, so `.catch` won't either.

Your cache gets populated, but your promise for `extendableEvent.waitUntil()` is never settled, so installation never completes.

Either scrap your promise variable / console.logs and return the cache.addAll like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(currCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        'app.js',
        'static/settings/visual/show-num-combos-in-range.png',
      ])
    })
  );
});
```

Or make your function async, like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(async function() {
    const cache = await caches.open(currCacheName);
    await cache.addAll([
        '/',
        'app.js',
        'static/settings/visual/show-num-combos-in-range.png',
    ]);
  }());
});
```

Comment: 1) The `return cache.addAll` approach doesn't work; the same thing happens as what I described in the question with the service worker remaining in the `installing` state.

Comment: 2) _"You are defining a variable called promise here, but it doesn't replace cache, which is the promise which needs to be fulfilled."_ I thought that `cache` is an object, not a promise, and that what needs to happen is that the `.then` block of `caches.open` needs to return something in order to trigger the `caches.open` promise to resolve (which would trigger `event.waitUntil` to finish). If so, I don't see why it would matter if you assign to the `promise` variable, because either way the `.then` block of `caches.open` is returning something.

Comment: 3) Even if assigning to the `promise` variable causes issues with `caches.open`, why would it cause issues with the `.then` and `.catch` blocks of `cache.addAll`?

Comment: 4) If there is indeed an issue with the `let promise = cache.addAll` approach, why does it work when I comment out `c7d016677eb7e912bc40.worker.js` and `f328c7e2b379df12fa4c.worker.js`?